# Angular Stepper : Is it possible to hide the vertical line for Active Step?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Is it possible to hide the vertical line for the Active Step in the stepper?

I would like to move the form contents to the left to have more working space on mobile phones. But I am unable to find the solution to hide the vertical line just for the Active Step.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Here is an sample stackblitz for the scenario mentioned.

https://stackblitz.com/angular/mdvpkdeqqry?file=app%2Fstepper-vertical-example.ts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After few tries I have found a way to hide the vertical line only for the active step

**If you want to hide it only for the active one you can use this**

```
mat-step-header[aria-selected=true] ~ .mat-stepper-vertical-line::before {
  border-left-width: 0;
}
```

This symbol `~` is used to mark that they are siblings.

**If you want to hide it for all steps you can use this**

```
.mat-stepper-vertical-line::before {
  border-left-width: 0;
}
```

To make this work you need to define these classes in `styles.css` in `src` folder

Comment: Thank you so much!!!  It worked like a charm! I had no idea I could use Aria properties to do conditional Css.

Answer (score 0):

The above step didn't work for me.

I solved it by inspecting the stepper line.

**Then I used this code for the horizontal line in the src/style.css**

```
**.mat-stepper-horizontal-line,  .mat-stepper-vertical-line{
  display: none;
}**
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me to remove the line for all steps:

```
::ng-deep .mat-stepper-vertical-line::before {
  display: none;
}
```